# Python: communicator not destroyed during global destruction

Tags: python, sys, ice

When I try to execute the following python script with:

> /usr/bin/python
>   /var/www/html/iPhone/inarrivo/python/addMurmurChannel.py 14
>   I receive error:
>   communicator not destroyed during global destruction.

What is the communicator and how I destroy it?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import Ice
import inspect
import sys
#Ice.loadSlice("/usr/local/murmur/ice/Murmur.ice")
Ice.loadSlice( '', ['-I' + Ice.getSliceDir(), "/usr/local/murmur/ice/Murmur.ice"])
import Murmur
newChannelName=sys.argv[1]
# Init ice
comm = Ice.initialize()
# Let Ice know where to go to connect to mumble
# Let Ice know where to go to connect to mumble
proxy = comm.stringToProxy("Meta -e 1.0:tcp -p 6502")
# Create a dynamic object that allows us to get a programmable interface for Mumble
meta = Murmur.MetaPrx.checkedCast(proxy)
# Get the server instance from the set of servers.
server = meta.getServer(1)
found=False
channels = server.getChannels()
for value in channels.itervalues():
    idChannel=value.id
    if value.name == newChannelName:
            found=True
            break
if found==False:
    server.addChannel(newChannelName, 0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When calling

```
ic = Ice.initialize()
```

a communicator is created.
you can destroy it like this:

```
if ic:
    # Clean up
    try:
        ic.destroy()
    except:
        traceback.print_exc()
        status = 1
```

refrence: https://doc.zeroc.com/display/Ice36/Writing+an+Ice+Application+with+Python#WritinganIceApplicationwithPython-WritingaClientinPython

Comment: Yes, in fact now I receive no error when running the command. For that matter, have you got any idea why the murmur server at taxiprofessional.net does not answer, notwithstanding it is installed and correctly running?

Comment: @FabrizioBartolomucci maybe you could set trace related properties to see what's wrong.

Comment: How to attain that?